# bt.plot() from the backtesting python library doesn't work

Tags: python, back-testing, backtrader, refinitiv-eikon

I'm trying to create a trading strategy, I used the **backtesting** library to do so. I used data from refinitiv using my app key, the eikon library and extracting the open, high, low, close, volume data of apple from the last two years with the **ek.get_timeseries function**. The problem is that after I try to plot my strategy using **bt.plot()** I got the following error:

`TypeError: bokeh.models.tools.Toolbar() got multiple values for keyword argument 'logo'`

I've tried upgrading the backtrader library:

`pip install --upgrade backtrader`

That didn't work. I couldn't find anything else

I still got the same error when I tried to run:

`bt.plot()`

This is my first time asking a question in stack overflow. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bokeh 3.2.2 breaks plotting, uninstall 3.2.2 and install 3.2.1 instead

```
pip uninstall bokeh
pip install bokeh==3.2.1
```

Comment: After uninstalling and installing the 3.2.1 version of bokeh I got the same error message when trying to run the bt.plot() function

Comment: Just in case, make sure you have removed and installed 3.2.1 run "pip list" command it will show to you all packages and versions. I had the same issue and fixed as simple as install the older version of boken.